# Перегрузка оператора operator=

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Мне нужно самой написать для класса `String` оператор `operator=`. Но он не правильно работает. Что я не правильно делаю?

```
String & String::operator=(const char other)
{
   delete[] mString;
   mSize = std::strlen(&other);
   mString = new char[mSize + 1];
   for (decltype(mSize) i = 0; i < mSize; ++i)
      mString[i] = other[&i];
   mString[mSize] = '\0';
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, что значит "неправильно работает".

Comment: `String & String::operator=(const char other)` вы присваиватете классу String 1 символ с типом char, не строку. `mString[i] = other[&i];` тут в строку mString на i место записывате байт который хранится по адресу переменной i (&i) со смещение на количество байт равное ASCII коду переданного символа `other`, т.е. дефакто какой-то неопределенный байт из памати, но всегда один и тот же. Пример, `const char * str = "abc"; str[1] == 1[str] == 'b'`.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, вы хотите это? К сожалению, сам класс вы не показываете, так что приходится гадать...

```
String& String::operator=(const char * other)
{
    delete[] mString;
    mSize = std::strlen(other);
    mString = new char[mSize + 1];
    strcpy(mString, other);
    return *this;
}
```

Для одного символа:

```
String& String::operator=(char other)
{
    delete[] mString;
    mSize = 1;
    mString = new char[mSize + 1];
    mString[0] = other; mString[1] = 0;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: нет я именно  хочу  написать String & String::operator=(const char other)

Comment: Вы хотите присваивать ОДИН символ? Кстати, тогда `const` ни к чему. Если нет, и это C-строка, то вы должны передавать `const char*`. Просто `char` - это никак не строка...

Comment: дка один символ

Comment: Сейчас допишу...

Comment: Я написала две функци const char* String::GetBuffer() const { return mString; } char* String::GetBuffer() { return mString; }

Comment: size_t String::GetSize() const { return mSize; }

Comment: чтобы использовать их в реализации оператора.

Comment: Ваши функции не пригодятся: они не позволяют **изменять сами члены** класса. Вы не сможете с их помощью изменить ни `mSize`, ни `mString`...

Answer (score 1):

Если вдруг у вас реализованы конструктор из C-строки и [большая тройка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B))(а она должна быть реализована раз уж вы динамически выделяете память), то можно сделать так:

```
String & String::operator=(const char *other){
   *this = String(other);
   return *this;
}
```

**UPD:** Раз уж опечатки нет, и у вас уже есть `operator=(const char*)`, то можно так:

```
String & String::operator=(const char c){
   char cstr[] = {c, 0};
   *this = cstr;
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: нет у меня есть оператор такой, я  хочу  написать  такой String & String::operator=(const char other) или String & String::operator=(const char& other)

Comment: @OlenaNovitska, сбивает с толку это `other[&i];` Такое ощущение, что вы хотели чтобы это был не одиночный символ, а строка

Comment: @  yrHeTaTeJlb ,  как  раз в этой строке я и не уверна что правильно анписала. И тут не уверена - mSize = other;

Comment: Я написала  две функци const char* String::GetBuffer() const
{
 return mString;
}

char* String::GetBuffer()
{
 return mString;
}

Comment: size_t String::GetSize() const
{
 return mSize;
}

Comment: чтобы использовать их в реализации оператора.

Comment: @OlenaNovitska, попробуйте мой код из upd. Если ваш `operator=(const char*)` работает правильно, то и мой код должен работать